# Source model "marketplace/source_option" not found for attribute "seller_id"

Tags: module, magento-1, error, marketplace

We have a magento website, which is currently in development stage.

we tried to install a open-source "market-place" plugin. It was not working as expected. After uninstalled the plugin. The website is showing the below error

> Source model "marketplace/source_option" not found for attribute "seller_id"

Please can you suggest how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the model containing the source data does not exist. In your site files, navigate to `app/code/(community or local)/(vendor name)/Marketplace/Model/Source/Option.php`.

If the file does not exist, that would be your issue and you would want to contact the developer and ask them to fix the issue for you.

Also, in the filepath that I gave you above, the sections in parentheses are placeholders because your question did not provide enough information to determine those two parts of the filepath.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the module has created an attribute "seller_id" which has a custom source model "marketplace/source_option".

Solutions:

1. You can reach the module provider to guide you through the uninstallation steps. Or
2. You can go to the database table "eaves_attribute" table and remove that particular attribute row.

Comment: He wants the marketplace module to work properly. Removing an attribute controlled by that module would most likely precent it from ever working properly.

Comment: He need to explain "**It was not working as expected**". What I understood from his question is "he tried to install the marketplace plugin and since it wasn't working he unistalled that plugin. Also he got the source model related error after that". I answered to that point.

Comment: Oh yes, I think you are right